# Apache Ignite: RDBMS Integration with .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, caching, ignite

I want to create a caching layer on top of an existing database using .NET/C#.

In the [Apache Ignite docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/external-storage#rdbms-integration), RDBMS integration is done with configuring the caches with an XML or directly in Java code, and then calling the loadCache method to load data from the database into the cluster.

How would I do get started using .NET/C#?

Comment: In .net/C# you specify the options when creating the object, have you looked at https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/thin-client

Comment: @Xavier I'm really new to apache ignite and just followed the latest docs -- right now I just start a cluster with the `bash ignite.sh` & passing an XML file with database credentials as a parameter

are there options that allow me to pass the database credentials (URL, user, password) when creating the object, or would I just need to [connect to an existing cluster](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/thin-client#connecting-to-cluster) that has those credentials already?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite provides the same Cache Store API for .NET/C#. You can implement `ICacheStore` that delegates to your existing database, then enable it with `CacheConfiguration.CacheStoreFactory` property in C#.

Sample implementations:

- [Entity Framework](https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Entity-Framework-Cache-Store/)
- [ADO.NET (raw SQL)](https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Ado-Net-Cache-Store/)

Those samples are a bit old and use full .NET Framework, but adapting them to .NET Core / EF Core should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the resources, but I'm just a little confused on how to establish a database connection -- I'm really new to apache ignite, and right now I just start nodes with `bash ignite.sh` script & passing an XML file with database credentials (URL, user, password) as a parameter to the script

Comment: @Mangled_Aura_Nada Hmm, do you expect Ignite to connect to your DB automatically and cache everything?

Comment: I think so - I'm really new to apache ignite, and I've just following the latest docs, so I'm not sure about what's possible/what's not possible

Answer (score 0):

There are two practical ways of running Ignite - either stand-alone, or inside your own code.

You can run Ignite.Net in stand-alone mode (`Apache.Ignite.exe`/`.dll`) but running plain Java one is more straightforward and is often enough. In this case, you may just use XML configuration to wire your database in.

You can also import Ignite to your code as library and configure/start node programmatically. Then, see the existing answer on configuring C# cache store.

Comment: In the case of using an XML configuration, after running `bash ignite.sh` (I'm starting a cluster via PuTTY) would I need to programmatically load the data from the database into the cache?

Comment: Yes. But I guess you can do that via C# API.